# ¿Cómo agregar permisos a mi aplicación en el servidor de Heroku?

Tags: php, php7, heroku

antes que nada, debo decir que no soy experto en hostings.
Bien, mi problema es que quiero subir mi página web a este servidor.
Todo iba bien, hasta que teclee el comando:

```
heroku git:remote -a sitio_de_prueba
```

Y la consola me lanza estos dos mensajes:

```
Error: You do not have permission to view on profile.
You need to have the view permission on this app.
Error ID: forbidden
```

Sinceramente no sé cómo hacerle, ya busqué en los exploradores.

Comment: `heroku login` ?

Comment: hice el respectivo login, pero cuando ejecuto [heroku git:remote -a] me muestra el error

Comment: Gracias por responder a tu pregunta. Entiendo que al ser un error en el nombre de tu sitio, probablemente termine cerrada como que "*no se puede reproducir*".

Answer (score 1):

Lo he resutlto, lo que me faltó fué el nombre de mi app de heroku, yo había escrito el nombre que tenía en mi host local; y mi error fué no haber escrito el nombre de mi app de heroku.
En este caso, el comando quedaría de esta manera:

```
heroku git:remote -a mi_app
```

Y con esto ya resuelto, pude subir mi sitio web.